# derive socket fd from 'struct sock'

Tags: sockets, networking, linux-kernel, system-calls

Is there a way to obtain a socket fd from object of type `struct sock` in the kernel? Quick look inside of `struct sock` doesn't help to find something that looks like socket descriptor. Basically I need what `socket()` syscall returns, is it not stored in 'sock' ?

I need to get `fd` at the point before a packet hits IP stack.

Thanks.

Comment: fd numbers exist on per-process basis only, so it is unclear what do you need when asking for fd in kernel.

Comment: @Martin, thanks for comment. Basically when I have 'struct sock' object I want to be able to know which `fd` in user space it corresponds to.

Comment: I mean, you probably need to start other way around. Take particular process' file descriptor table, walk through it and check if some record points to the socket in question. One and the same socket can be referred by more fds in one ore more user-space tasks.  (Sorry, no detailed answer on how to do it just now, as I'd need to check few details and do not have time now, maybe later if nobody will be faster answering.)

Answer (score 3):

For each process there is a **table of file descriptors**, which maps file descriptors to `struct file` objects. You may iterate over this table using `iterate_fd()` function.

For any `struct file` you may determine which `struct sock` object it corresponds using `sock_from_file()` function.

In total:

```
/*
 * Callback for iterate_fd().
 *
 * If given file corresponds to the given socket, return fd + 1.
 * Otherwise return 0.
 *
 * Note, that returning 0 is needed for continue the search.
 */
static int check_file_is_sock(void* s, struct file* f, int fd)
{
    int err;
    struct sock* real_sock = sock_from_file(f, &err);
    if(real_sock == s)
        return fd + 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
// Return file descriptor for given socket in given process.
int get_fd_for_sock(struct sock* s, struct task* p)
{
    int search_res;
    task_lock(p);
    // This returns either (fd + 1) or 0 if not found.
    search_res = iterate_fd(p->files, 0, &check_file_is_sock, s);
    task_unlock(p);

    if(search_res)
        return search_res - 1;
    else
        return -1; // Not found
}
```

Comment: Note that it's entirely possible that there will be no process that has the socket open, more than one process that has the socket open, and even processes that have the same socket open more than once.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, thanks for the answer. Am I right that that the code you're suggesting would work only in process context? Otherwise how would I obtain a 'task_struct' pointer? I need to get `fd` at the point before a packet hits IP stack.

Comment: This needn't to be a *process context*. You may store `task_struct` at some previous point, and use it here. Or iterate over all tasks for find one, which contains given `sock` object. In any case you need `task_struct` object, as a file descriptor is *meaningless* without it. Exactly that is stated in the comment to your question and my answer.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, where can I obtain a reference to `task_struct` when inside of the `__netif_receive_skb_core() -> sch_handle_ingress()` code path? At that point only `skb` is available, there is potentially a way to get to `file` via `skb->sk`.